# One of my if statements is getting passed over

Tags: function, python-3.x, if-statement

"HFormBio" will execute BioFam2 and BioFam3, but skips over BioFam1's question.
What am I doing wrong? or, How can I do it better?

The globals are calling x = '' containers for the input.

I want to ask BioFam1 if FamHero ='Yes' , but that question is getting skipped, but BioFam2 and BioFam3 are not.

```
def HFormBio ():
        global FamHero
        global FamDead
        global BioFam1
        global BioFam2
        global BioFam3

        if FamHero == 'Yes':
            BioFam1 = input('What is their Name(s)? ')
            return BioFam1
        if FamDead == 'Yes':
            BioFam2 = input('Were they supers as well? ')
            BioFam3 = input('Were they registered Heroes? ')
            return BioFam2, BioFam3


    def HForm ():
        global FirstName
        global LastName
        global HeroName
        global Predest
        global Nature
        global Gender
        global Attraction
        global FamDead
        global HeroApp

        print(HeroApp)
        FirstName = input('What is your First Name? ')
        LastName = input('What is your Last Name? ')
        HeroName = input('What is your Hero Name? ')
        Nature = input('Are you Good or Evil? ')
        Gender = input('Are you Male or Female? ')
        Attraction = input('Are you attracted to Men or Women? ')
        FamHero = input('Do you have any family that are registered Heroes? ')
        FamDead = input('Are any of your family members dead due to murder? ')  
        return FirstName, LastName, HeroName, Predest, Nature, Gender, Attraction, FamHero
    HForm ()
    HFormBio ()
    License = ' DEPARTMENT FOR THE REGULATION OF POWERED RESOURCES:\n\n HERO LICENSE: #13337\n Name: {0}\n Gender: {1}\n Age: 20\n Marital Status: Single \n Attracted to: {2}\n Hero Name: {3}\n Nature: {4}\n Attracted to: {5}\n Registered Family: {6}\n'.format(FirstName, Gender, Attraction, HeroName, Nature, Attraction, FamDead)
    return License
```

Output:

```
Hero Application:  Form 0113.4
What is your First Name? Daniel
What is your Last Name? Lewis
What is your Hero Name? W
Are you Good or Evil? Good
Are you Male or Female? Male
Are you attracted to Men or Women? Women
Do you have any family that are registered Heroes? Yes 
#BioFam1's question is missing.
Are any of your family members dead due to murder? Yes
#BioFam2/3 are executing
Were they supers as well? Yes 
Were they registered Heroes? Yes
 DEPARTMENT FOR THE REGULATION OF POWERED RESOURCES:

 HERO LICENSE: #13337
 Name: Daniel
 Gender: Male
 Age: 20
 Marital Status: Single
 Attracted to: Women
 Hero Name: W
 Nature: Good
 Attracted to: Women
 Registered Family: Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do what I was looking for after Eric pointed out that I did not declare the appropriate global.
I changed the code below.

```
print(HeroApp)
        FirstName = input('What is your First Name? ')
        LastName = input('What is your Last Name? ')
        HeroName = input('What is your Hero Name? ')
        Nature = input('Are you Good or Evil? ')
        Gender = input('Are you Male or Female? ')
        Attraction = input('Are you attracted to Men or Women? ')
        FamHero = input('Do you have any family that are registered Heroes? ')
        if FamHero == 'Yes':
            BioFam1 = input('What is their Name(s)? ')
        FamDead = input('Are any of your family members dead due to murder? ')  
        if FamDead == 'Yes':
            BioFam2 = input('Were they supers as well? ')
            BioFam3 = input('Were they registered Heroes? ')
        return FirstName, LastName, HeroName, Predest, Nature, Gender, Attraction, FamHero, BioFam1, BioFam2, BioFam3
```

Answer (score 0):

FamHero is not declared global in HForm.

You really should make a class Hero and use class variables like self.FamHero

Comment: I haven't gotten into making classes yet, could you give me an example of how i could do that?